# Catching a random number. i need to shift the characters of input and encode them

Tags: c#, encryption, random

so i need to encode whatever input is given.
Like a user types : "ABC"  it should shift to "JKL"
i know we can do this by defining a character to each word. Like A = J , B = K
but the problem is it would come up with same encoding every time.
so is there any way to forward the characters randomly? and if random number can be recorded so the string could be decoded
Any one know a way? I'll really appreciate it.

## Edit 1:  Its basically my project, to encrypt any given file using bit shifting then adding dummy data and then compressing it by Vector Quantization.

So my first step was to read and write a file that's done. Now I want to shift the characters forward, I can either do it by converting them to binary and then use bit shift or I can shift the characters forward. But I wanted to know if there is any way through which I can **CATCH** that random generated number, So at the time of decoding I can USE that number to decrypt the characters correctly.

And I have roughly made a code.. I will be updating it soon. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: So you want that one string "ABC" is not always "encrypted" to the same output? Or is it that two "A"'s in the same string should not both map to "J" ?

Comment: Really need more information from you.  What have you tried so far?  This isn't a good writing website

Answer (score 1):

You can seed a random generator, which will make it return the same sequence of random numbers each time. That way you can use a key for the encryption:

```
int key = 42;
Random rnd = new Random(key);
```

Now you can convert each character using a random number. For example for the character range A-Z:

```
char c = 'X';

int code = c - 'A'; // Bring the character code into the range 0-25
code = code + rnd.Next(26); // encrypt
code = code % 26; // roll over for codes > 25
c = (char)('A' + code); // convert code to character
```

Decrypting would be the same except subtracting the random number.

Comment: +1. Or OP can use XOR function if he is not limited to printable alphabet letters.